#  I want to validate when time selected from drop down list is past current time

Tags: php, javascript

I'm new to java script. I want to validate wether the time selected from drop down list is past the current time.

For example:
The user selects `2:00pm` while the current time is `1:00pm`, now the following error should popup:

> The time you have selected is before the current time.

How can I do this? Below is my drop down list.

```
<?php
$start = strtotime('12:00am');
$end = strtotime('11:30pm');

echo '<select name="time">';
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 1800)
{
    echo '<option>' . date('g:i a', $i);
}
echo '</select>';


?>
```

I have tried the following however I could not make this working.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language=JavaScript>
function validate_time(elmnt)
{
    var date_in = new date(elmnt);
    var date_now = new date(); //returns current date by default;
    if( date_in<date_now ){ alert('The time you have selected is before the current time.');
}   
</script>

</head>
<body>



<div align="left">
<?php


$start = strtotime('12:00am');
$end = strtotime('11:30pm');

echo '<select name="time">';
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 1800)
{
echo '<option>' . date('g:i a', $i);
}
echo '<select name=time onchange="OnChange(this.form.select)">';
echo '</select>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write an event handler function for the onchange() property of the select element. Put it in a < script > tag in the header section of your document. Then attach it to your select element. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language=JavaScript>
function validate_time(elmnt)
{
    var date_in = new date(elmnt);
    var date_now = new date(); //returns current date by default;
    if( date_in<date_now ){ alert('The time you have selected is before the current time.');
}
```

Comment: The date constructor takes a string, but maybe not formatted the way yours is. Try casting it to utc. Otherwise this is how events are handled.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this in two ways.
you can make $start = date("U"); this sets start to the current time.

you could validate on the php side. by checking date("g:i a") > $_POST['time']

in order to do it in JavaScript you rely that the system time is set to the correct value as JavaScript is client side.

the easiest way in javascript is to load in jquery. and set the id="time" as well as name="time".

then you can do an on change function and compare it to now using ...
var now = new Date();